# Equations not updating on all sheets in workbook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to do some simple calculations on each sheet of a workbook.  However, the calculations do not update on all sheets.  Can you help me get the calculations to appear on all sheets in the workbook?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets
    xRow = 1
    With xWks
        .Cells(xRow, 12) = "Meas-LO"
        .Cells(xRow, 13) = "Meas-Hi"
        .Cells(xRow, 14) = "Marginal"
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Range("L2").Formula = "=G2+I2"
        Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
        Range("M2").Formula = "=I2-F2"
    Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
        End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

     Next xWks
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated my question...sorry, its just VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the For Loop, `Activate` each worksheet as shown below. If you do not activate the worksheet, the first sheet will always remain activated and the value contained in the variable 'LastRow' will not be what you want(from 2nd Iteration onwards) as it makes use of activesheet.

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets
    xRow = 1
    With xWks              
        .Activate                    'Activating the worksheet
        .Cells(xRow, 12) = "Meas-LO"
        .Cells(xRow, 13) = "Meas-Hi"
        .Cells(xRow, 14) = "Marginal"
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Range("L2").Formula = "=G2+I2"
        Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
        Range("M2").Formula = "=I2-F2"
    Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
        End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

     Next xWks
End Sub
```